# Go to next page when True

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

JavaScript was created as follows: If the diction value is true, I want to go to another page, and if it is false, I want to let you go to Home. What should I do?

```
async function predict() {
    // predict can take in an image, video or canvas html element
    var image = document.getElementById("face-image")
    const prediction = await model.predict(image, false);
    prediction.sort((a,b) => parseFloat(b.probability) - parseFloat(a.probability));
    switch (prediction[0].className){
        case "True":
            resultMessege = "성공"
            break;
        case "False":
            resultMessege = "실패."
            break;
        default:
            resultMessege = "알 수 없는 오류가 발생하였습니다. 다시 시도해보시길 바랍니다."
    }
    $('.result-message').html(resultMessege);
```

Comment: do you mean redirecting the page for a user?

Comment: @AzizaKasenova Yes, it is. I want you to go to the next page when it's true and to the home screen when it's false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If redirecting to another page is, what you want to achive, then it is simpy this:

```
window.location.href = '/nextpage';
```

Comment: How do I get to the appropriate Url used by Django? EX) <a href="{% url 'app:login' %}">

Comment: As far as I know you can ´window.location.href = '/nextpage';´ with a absolute path. Your snippet `<a href="{% url 'app:login' %}">` shows a shortcut for a later rendering of a url. I don´t believe you can use that shortcut inside of your script, as it should only be used in HTML.